# Clarification with the base max function

Tags: r, max

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
m <- data.frame(a = c(".","1",2:10), 
                b = c(".","2",4:12), 
                c = c(rep(".",11)))
```

I use apply to get the max value of each row:

```
maxrowval <- apply(m,1,max)  
fin <- cbind(m,maxrowval)
```

The problem is that rows 9 and 10 of `fin` does not give the max values.
I must be missing something here but can't point to the source of the problem. Maybe something to do with factors and the levels. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `m` is not numeric. All the columns are factors (and ordered) and hence the result. Check `str(m)` and `ordered(m$a)` for further details

Comment: @Sumedh - they are not ordered, well, not explicitly like `ordered()` gives anyway.

Comment: Oh, so the `<` symbol doesn't mean anything?

Comment: @Sumedh - that's because you called `ordered()` on it. `m$a` is just a factor, without explicit order. Though the levels are placed in such an order as per `levels(m$a)`. See `all.equal(ordered(m$a), m$a)`

Comment: @thelatemail So when applying max different levels are compared (as set by the default order)? Could one away around be  reordering the levels and then call max? But this may be problematic for large datasets.

Comment: @thisisrg - the solution would probably be to call `m[] <- lapply(m, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)) )` so you're dealing with all numeric data first. Otherwise it's just a nightmare to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the character issue mentioned in the comments with the `max` function and removing `"-Inf"` from the results.

```
foo <- function(x){
  tmp <- max(as.numeric(as.character(x)), na.rm = T)
  ifelse(tmp == "-Inf", NA, tmp)
}
apply(m, 1, foo)
[1] NA    2    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
```